# Refresh component with Angular

Tags: angular

I just want to refresh my component with Angular every x seconds.

I tried this:

```
setTimeout(() => {
  location.reload();
}, 10000);
```

It works but refreshes the whole of my page, while I'm looking to refresh only my component.

Comment: What do you mean *"refresh my component"* - what's the *problem* you're trying to solve?

Comment: By refresh, you mean rerender? - What is the reason, it should automatically rerender if your data changes. If for some reason is doesn't you can you the ngOnChanges hook

Comment: I want just reload my component every x second without refresh all the page

Answer (score 0):

If your data changes, It automatically reloads your data.

But if your intention is reloading your view without hard refresh. You can use

```
this.router.navigateByUrl('/RefrshComponent', {skipLocationChange: true}).then(()=>
this.router.navigate(["Your actualComponent"]));
```